# cycle the LEDS IN ATMEGA8515

Tags: atmega

I want to read the switches next to the LEDS and cycle the LEDS from 0 to whichever switch is pressed
if none are pressed cycle through all of them with the delay.For this i have used timer0. Since I work on
atmega8515. I used INT0. 
Here is my implementation:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define BIT(n) (1 << n) 

volatile uint8_t led, k, switches, i , j = 1;
            /* uint8_t is the same as unsigned char */
int main(void)
{



    DDRB = 0xff;                /* use all pins on PortB for output */

    led = 1;                    /* init variable representing the LED state */
    PORTB = 0XFF;

    cli( );

    TCCR0|=(1<<CS02) |(1<<CS00);

 //Enable Overflow Interrupt Enable
   TIMSK|=(1<<TOIE0);

 //Initialize Counter
   TCNT0=0;


   GICR = BIT(INT0);
    MCUCR = BIT(ISC01) | BIT(ISC00);

   sei( );

    for ( ; ;);



}


ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
{

  if(switches == 0xff)
  {
    PORTB = ~led;           /* invert the output since a zero means: LED on */
        led <<= 1;              /* move to next LED */
        if (!led)               /* overflow: start with Pin B0 again */
        {
            led = 1;
        }
  }     
  else
  {
    for (k = 0; k< 8;k++)
    {
        j =  switches & (1 << k);

        if(j == 0)
        {
           for(i=1;i<=(k +1);i++)
            {   
                j = 1;
                PORTB =  ~j;
                j = 1 << i;

                _delay_ms(100);     //without this delay it doesnt cycle the LEDS from to whichever switch is pressed
            }   

    }
}
}
```

But using delay loops in ISR is a bad programming practice. How to use the same timer instead of the delay?

Comment: If you have a timer that you're using to trigger the ISR, why do you need to use a delay function?  Why can't you just update the LED status every time the ISR fires?

Comment: If you see my ISR it has if and else loop

Comment: I see that.  But why?  Like I said, just update the LED port status *once* in each ISR call.  If the ISR fires at regular intervals, you will get an animation effect.

Comment: If you see my ISR it has if and else loop .In the if loop, I am cycling the LEDS(WHEN NONE OF THE switch are pressed). In the else loop , I am cycling the LEDS upto the switch which is pressed. There I have  another for loop to cycle the LED.  I am not sure, if my implementation is correct for cycling the LEDS upto the switch which is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the ISR, you should just update the LED status and in the main loop you could set the PORTB and read the switches values. In your code, it seems occupy so much time in ISR.